# Understanding a complex wget command

Tags: 14.04, command-line, wget

I was just going through a tutorial online **[HERE](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html#pgrouting)**. If you see the last command in the section:

```
# For workshops at conferences and events:
# Download and install from http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo/wiki/Live_GIS_Workshop_Install
wget --no-check-certificate https://launchpad.net/~georepublic/+archive/pgrouting/+files/pgrouting-workshop_[version]_all.deb
```

There is the following in the above command:

```
[version]
```

So is that exactly how i have to execute the command or am i expected to pass a certain value or replace [version] during execution time ?

If i execute the command as it is, i get the following message:

> Reusing existing connection to launchpad.net:443. HTTP request sent,
>   awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2015-09-01 17:26:30 ERROR 404: Not
>   Found.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to supply [version] with an actual version number, which it looks like you can obtain from [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo/wiki/Live_GIS_Workshop_Install). So for example:

```
    wget --no-check-certificate https://launchpad.net/~georepublic/+archive/ubuntu/pgrouting/+files/pgrouting-workshop_2.0.6-ppa1_all.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to replace `[version]` by the version.
This is like `/path/to/your/home/directory/`, it's a kind of variable which is different depending on the user.